# Checking duplicated when filling SQL Table using SQLAlchemy/Pandas to_SQL

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I would like to dump data into my mysql database. If I want to add addtional data, I am using the same cvs file as shown below but extended with the additional line.

If i restart my code the data just gets included again plus the additional line. This means my data doubles plus one.

How can I check the data base and exclude doubles, so just that the newest line gets included?

The initial csv file looks the following:

```
Ticker;Name;Country
A;Pablo;USA
B;Nico;USA
C;Dimi;USA
D;George;USA
E;Will;USA
F;Paul;USA
```

Extended csv File:

```
Ticker;Name;Country
A;Pablo;USA
B;Nico;USA
C;Dimi;USA
D;George;USA
E;Will;USA
F;Paul;USA
G;Tom;Russia
```

The code looks like the following:

```
import sqlalchemy as sqlal
import pandas as pd

mysql_engine = sqlal.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://xxx/Test_Schema',poolclass=sqlal.pool.NullPool)

mysql_engine.raw_connection()

if not mysql_engine.dialect.has_table(mysql_engine, 'master_data'):  
    metadata = sqlal.MetaData(mysql_engine)

    sqlal.Table('master_data', metadata,
                sqlal.Column('Ticker', sqlal.String(20), nullable=False, primary_key=True),
                sqlal.Column('Name', sqlal.String(250), nullable=True),
                sqlal.Column('Country', sqlal.String(10), nullable=True)
    )
    metadata.create_all(mysql_engine)  

df_csv = pd.read_csv('TestFile.csv', encoding='cp1252', sep=';', index_col=0).dropna()
print(df_csv)
df_csv.to_sql(name='master_data', con=mysql_engine, if_exists = 'append', chunksize=900, index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in such a way but maybe there is something nicer?

```
import sqlalchemy as sqlal
import pandas as pd

mysql_engine = sqlal.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://xxx/Test_Schema',poolclass=sqlal.pool.NullPool)

mysql_engine.raw_connection()

if not mysql_engine.dialect.has_table(mysql_engine, 'master_data'):  
    metadata = sqlal.MetaData(mysql_engine)

    sqlal.Table('master_data', metadata,
                sqlal.Column('Ticker', sqlal.String(20), nullable=False, primary_key=True),
                sqlal.Column('Name', sqlal.String(250), nullable=True),
                sqlal.Column('Country', sqlal.String(10), nullable=True)
    )
    metadata.create_all(mysql_engine)  

df_csv = pd.read_csv('TestFile.csv', encoding='cp1252', sep=';', index_col=0).dropna()

for i in range(len(df_csv)):
    try:
        df_csv.iloc[i:i+1].to_sql(name='master_data',if_exists='append',con = mysql_engine, chunksize=900, index=True)
    except sqlal.exc.IntegrityError as e:
        pass #or any other action
```